# ImportError: No module named htmlmin.minify

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, pgadmin-4

Command:

```
python3 pgadmin4-1.1/web/setup.py
```

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'htmlmin.minify'
```

I had a similar problem with `htmlmin` module, but I solved with:

```
sudo pip3 install htmlmin
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: did you try running the `setup.py` again after installing the missing dependency? if so can you try opening a terminal and doing the same command? and putting the error here.

Comment: I solved with "sudo pip3 install django-htmlmin". Thanks foryour attention.

Comment: I have installed `htmlmin` with pip and it is in the right place. Python can import it but iPython can't. Strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved with:

```
sudo pip3 install django-htmlmin
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every time you pull new code make sure to run

```
pip3 install -r pgadmin4-1.1/requirements_py3.txt
```